# d3 on click for circles not working

Tags: svg, d3.js, onclick

I have a simple, modified version of the cluster diagram from D3 that I'm trying to get to respond to mouse clicks. It works for the links between nodes but not the nodes themselves.  It looks to me like I'm treating lines and nodes (svg circles) the same, and yet nodes do not work... but of course D3 itself is generating those lines...

I have a very simple demo of it on JSFiddle at:  http://jsfiddle.net/gaelicmichael1965/c2XWg/8/

What's going on? I would certainly appreciate any help that could be offered.

```
var nodes = tree.nodes(flareData),
  links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Create all of the link paths (using diagonal projection)
  // Uses D3 functions to create SVG elements
var link = vis.selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)
.enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", diagonal)
  .on("click", function(d, index) {
          console.log("Selected line");
  });

  // Create all of the g-elements that contain node svg-elements
var node = vis.selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", 4.5)
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + d.y + ")"; })
    // In actuality, will need to access property of d
  .style( "fill", function(d, index) { return fillColors[index%4] } )
  .on("click", function(d, index) {
      console.log("Selected node");
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have stems from your CSS. In particular, you are turning off [pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) for the nodes, meaning that mouse-triggered events (such as `"click"`) are not processing:

```
.node {
    font-size: 12px;
    pointer-events: none; /*Comment out or remove this line*/
}
```

Comment out or remove the `pointer-events:none;` line in your CSS to allow the nodes to be the target of your `"click"` event.

Comment: Thank you!  I of course just copied this from D3 and didn't notice!

Comment: @user3780094: glad to help! Please feel free to [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you feel it solved your problem.